# laravel 5. Короткий путь в корень папка public. Сервер XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel

Когда на браузере пишу localhost/laravel.local/ он должен зайти в localhost/laravel.local/public/index.php
 Как сделать?

Comment: А сейчас что? Каким сервером пользуетесь?

Comment: сервер XAMPP @Etki